# Using Optional.map() instead of Optional.ifPresent() to execute code that may throw an exception and returning any exceptions as the return value

Tags: java, exception, option-type

I'm trying to get a feel for the proper way to use the `java.util.Optional` class.  Given the following example code:

```
public void doSomething(File destDir, String classifier) throws IOException {
    URL resourceRoot = introspectionService.getResourceRoot(pattern);

    if (resourceRoot != null) {
        JarFile jarFile = (JarFile) resourceRoot.getContent(); //this can throw IOException
        ... snipped for brevity ...
    }
}
```

I would like to convert this method to use an `Optional<URL>` value from the introspectionService.

```
public void doSomething(File destDir, String classifier) throws IOException {
    Optional<URL> resourceRoot = introspectionService.getResourceRoot(pattern);

    resourceRoot.ifPresent(rootUrl-> {
        JarFile jarFile = (JarFile) rootUrl.getContent(); //this can throw IOException
        ... snipped for brevity ...
    });
}
```

This obviously fails to compile because the signature of ifPresent() takes a Consumer which does not allow exceptions to be thrown from the accept() method.

I came up with the following work-around and was wondering if there is a better way:

```
public void doSomething(File destDir, String classifier) throws IOException {
    Optional<URL> resourceRoot = introspectionService.getResourceRoot(pattern);

    Optional<IOException> ioException = 
    resourceRoot.map(rootUrl-> {
        try {
            JarFile jarFile = (JarFile) rootUrl.getContent(); //this can throw IOException
        ... snipped for brevity ...
            return null;
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
            return e;
        }
    });
    if (ioException.isPresent()) {
        throw ioException.get();
    }
}
```

Is there a better alternative?

Comment: This is not a good use for Optional.map.  Just use `if (resourceRoot.isPresent())`.  Your code will be much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: As MC Emperor suggested, you can catch the `IOException` and then throw an `UncheckedIOException`.

---

Here's a more generic way to do it by making the compiler think a checked exception is really unchecked.

```
resourceRoot.map(rootUrl-> {
    try {
        JarFile jarFile = (JarFile) rootUrl.getContent(); //this can throw IOException
    ... snipped for brevity ...
        return null;
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        sneakyThrow(e);
    }
});
```

You can define `sneakyThrow` as given below (I got it from [this](https://www.baeldung.com/java-sneaky-throws) article). Because of type erasure and type inference (`T` is inferred to either `RuntimeException` or `Error`), it compiles without errors but still runs as if you actually said `throw e`.

```
public static <T extends Throwable> void sneakyThrow(Throwable t) throws T {
    throw (T) t;
}
```

Lombok has a `SneakyThrows` annotation that helps you do this.

This way, you don't have to wrap it in a `RuntimeException` or anything - the exception is simply an `IOException` at runtime too.

Comment: There is also an `UncheckedIOException` class available.

Comment: @MCEmperor True, but this is a more generic option. I'll add that to my answer though, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not the right place to use `Optional` while you have other classes that handle the same thing you looking for.

it's worth to look at the [Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html) class and change your design accordingly

Comment: While I totally agree with you that `Optional` is not necessary here, this is more of a comment than an answer. Could you give a toy example of how you would change it?

Comment: Unfortunately he coupled the question with Optional which I don't have the entire context. If he share more info about what he wants to achieve I can help

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't post the real code as it would violate company policy.  This particular application is a spring-boot application. The application is searching through its classpath for this one particular dpendency so that it can extract from it, specific jar files that are themselves spring-boot applications to specific directories.

For the purposes of this discussion though, it is irrelevant.  I'm asking a very specific question about how best to convert a block of exception-prone code to run inside of a lambda expression that is passed to Optional.ifPresent().

Comment: Lambda means a functional programming principle, which means you are implementing a free side-effect function and you are here breaking it by adding an exception (one of the side-effect)